# What is the difference between free current and displacement current?

Tags: displacement-current

So the displacement current is introduced to make Ampere's Law consistent with time-dependent currents, and then becomes $$\oint \vec{B}d\vec{l}=\mu_0(I+I_d).$$ I am struggling to understand exactly what the displacement current is, and how to determine whether or not it exists in a situation.

For example, I was trying to solve the problem of computing the magnetic field between the plates of a parallel-plate capacitor in an electric circuit. The solution to the problem states that there is no current between the plates, but there is a displacement current. So Ampere's Law becomes $$\oint \vec{B}d\vec{l}=\mu_0I_d.$$ Why in this case is there a displacement current but no free current between the plates?

What situations would result in a free current but no displacement current?

Can someone explicitly explain what the displacement current actually is?

Comment: Displacement current is simply the time derivative of the electric field.  It involves no transfer of charge or any other material at all.  I think "displacement current" is unfortunate nomenclature, but we're stuck with it.